# How to change the reference path for get_filename_component in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm using `get_filename_component` in cmake to get the absolute path of a possibly relative path given in a variable.

And I want to do an out-of-tree/out-of-source-build.

It seems to me that `get_filename_component` is using `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` as reference-path.

Is there a way to change that or to workaround it?

One way I tried is to prefix my potential relative path with `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` but that stops working of the path given is not relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your relative path is *always* relative to `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, then you can handle this pretty easily using [`if(IS_ABSOLUTE ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aif):

```
if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE ${MyPath})
  set(MyAbsPath ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${MyPath})
endif()
```

If the subject file or dir exists at CMake run time, then you can always do a [`find_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_file) call, passing the possible `NAMES` and `PATHS`.  If the file exists and is found, the resulting variable will hold the full path to the file.

Or you can use the `if(EXISTS ...)` signature of `if` to check for the existence or not of the given file.